# R - import excel file as dataframe including a new column with Excel file name

Tags: r, excel, filenames

I am new to R and I have 2 questions:

I would like to import an excel file as a dataframe and at the same time adding a new column to dataframe that would include the Excel file name. Eg. the Excel file name is A_2011.xlsx and I would like to create a new column ("filename") in a dataframe = A_2011 by extracting it from Excel file name.

Given that I have a multiple dataframes in my environment and I want to create a function that will add a new column "FILE" to all dataframes in my environment and the value in the column FILE would be equal to each dataframe´s name as follows:

```
dataframes:      column "FILE"
A_1                      A_1
A_2                      A_2 
A_3                      A_3
A_4                      A_4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you need to change "mydir/" to whatever the name of your folder is.

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)

files <- list.files("mydir/", pattern = "A_", full.names = TRUE) %>%
    set_names()

merged <- map_dfr(files, read_excel, .id = "filename")
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that `set_names()` is not a base function. So you should import `{purrr}` before doing the `files <- ...` line.